# Run program in subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a Windows batch script to run 2 programs through a bunch of folders. I'm not an expert at shell scripting but I try my best.

Here's what I'm trying to run through each folder...

The input for program1 is a .extension1 file which then produces a .extension2 file which then is run through program2 to generate what I need.

Before I run the script I cd into the folder. The programs are copied to the folder because they only work in the current working directory.

```
copy C:\program1 .   
copy C:\program2 .
for %i in (*.extension1) do program1 "%i"    
for %i in (*.extension2) do program2 "%i"
```

The data folder shown above contains hundreds of folders that I need to run the program in. I'd like to be able to do this in one big batch script.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\one"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /r %%a IN (*.ext1) DO (
 PUSHD "%%~dpa"
 ECHO(c:\program1 "%%~nxa"
 popd
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

In all probability, this is all you would need - or at least, this is a framework.

Note that the routine will simply `ECHO` the required commands. This allows a harmless test (on a representative sub-tree) to ensure that the process should work on the entire tree.

Changing `ECHO(c:\program1` to `c:\program1` *should* execute the first program on each `.ext1` file in the sub-tree. It would be unusual for a program to check that the file exists within the same directory as the executable - if it won't take a path, then "the current directory" would be assumed.

You don't say whether the program `program1` produces a file called `whatever.ext2` from `whatever.ext1` or whether it produces `somethingradicallydifferent.ext2`. In all probability, the same name would be used.

If that is the case, then to run the second program, simply add after

```
 ECHO(c:\program1 "%%~nxa"
```

```
 ECHO(c:\program2 "%%~na.ext2"
```

Otherwise, simply repeat the entire block, changing `ext1` to `ext2`

(I'll assume you can figure out that I've abbreviated the extensions)

If, on the off-chance the program(s) need to be in the same directory, then replace

```
 ECHO(c:\program1 "%%~nxa"
```

with

```
 echo n|C:\program1 . >nul 2>nul
 ECHO(program1 "%%~nxa"
```

(and ditto for program 2, obviously). Here the `n` is `echo`ed into the `copy`, so that the `copy` will only take place once. This could be improved but is probably only a theoretical requirement anyway since it's 99.9999% likely that executing `c:\program?` will work quite happily.